# How to Start Parachain Node with disabled P2P?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, collator

Is there a way to start a parachain node in CI and instruct it through a binary flag not to sync with the relay chain? I think it would be the same to say I want the P2P functionality to be off. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run with `--in-peers 0 --out-peers 0` to prevent `sync` connecting to any peers.

Answer (score 3):

Specifying the option `--reserved-only` does spawn a private network. If the `--reserved-nodes` option is missing or if it contains invalid multiaddresses, the node won't connect and sync with other nodes.

When launching a node, the options after the double dash `--` affect the relay chain, e.g. `./parachain --reserved-only` targets the parachain, `./parachain -- --reserved-only` targets the relay chain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I want to start an isolated parachain node in CI, should I be passing both `--reserved-only -- --reserved-only`? I only need this node temporarily to read metadata.

Comment: @demisx If you plan to completely isolate the node, i.e. neither the parachain nor the relaychain should connect to other peers, than this combination of command options is suitable.